# gca and latest version of Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I've just installed the latest version of Matplotlib (3.4.1). When I use some code with the following line

```
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
```

I get the following warning:

> ```
> Calling gca() with keyword arguments was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.4. 
> Starting two minor releases later, gca() will take no keyword arguments.  
> The gca() function should only be used to get the current axes,
> or if no axes exist, create new axes with default keyword arguments.
> To create a new axes with non-default arguments,
> use plt.axes() or plt.subplot().
> ```

How do I get round this so my code does not give this warning?

Comment: At least you've got a warning. I'm using 3.6.1 and it's just fails with "gca() got an unexpected keyword argument 'projection'". Using add_subplot instead helped though.

Answer (score 73):

You can try:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
```

Answer (score 9):

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.subplot(projection='3d')

plt.plot([0, v1[0]], [0, v1[1]], [0, v1[2]], 'b')
plt.plot([0, v2[0]], [0, v2[1]], [0, v2[2]], 'r')
```

or

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

ax.plot([0, v1[0]], [0, v1[1]], [0, v1[2]], 'b')
ax.plot([0, v2[0]], [0, v2[1]], [0, v2[2]], 'r')
```

instead of

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot([0, v1[0]], [0, v1[1]], [0, v1[2]], 'b')
ax.plot([0, v2[0]], [0, v2[1]], [0, v2[2]], 'r')
```

I hope this was helpful,

Answer (score 0):

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax =fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
```

It resolves the error, and it's much cleaner than the other methods.